# Shell script to find the list of a keys inside a key in Yaml file

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, yaml

I have a yaml file

```
info:
  description: Api
  contact:
    name: Api
tags:
  - name: ""
    description: ""
paths:
  /data1/1:
    post:
      tags:
        - "tag1"
  /data2/2:
    post:
      tags:
        - "tag2"
  /data3/3:
    post:
      tags:
        - "tag3"
```

I want to get the number of the keys under **`paths:`** key, which is **`3`** here. Need this in a shell script.

Comment: You have tagged your question with the [tag:awk] tag. Does that mean you have tried to use `awk` to solve this?  What issues did you have with doing this?

Comment: I don't want to use the external tools or libs; native way is appreciated

Comment: Native in what sense? The shell does not have a built in `awk` interpreter.

Comment: but still we dont install awk explicitly - I just want to skip the installation part of any tools - awk is pre-installed and pretty comfortable

Comment: Try : grep -v "name" example.yml | grep -c "-"  - which is based on your example.

Comment: What's a "key" in your example? You've said you want to count "keys" under paths but you haven't told us what a "key" is or how to recognize it in your data. Which of the strings `/data1/1:` or `post:` or `tags:` or `- "tag2"` is a "key"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This MAY be what you're trying to do, using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:

```
$ awk '!/^ /{f=/^paths:/} f && /^  \//{cnt++} END{print cnt+0}' file
3
```

It mostly depends what you mean by a "key".

Comment: Thank you @ed-morton; the response vary if there is an additional space after the **paths:** key; is there a way to dynamically handle it?

Comment: updated that in the answer and sent for approval

Comment: The edit you proposed would have made the script only work in GNU awk and doesn't make sense since it was trying to skip lines that were empty or all blanks but the existing script already does that. If the sample input in your question doesn't adequately represent your real data and causes the script I posted to fail then edit your question to update your example so I can see what's happening and test with it to come up with a robust, portable solution.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that by "number of keys under `paths`" you mean the number of top-level entries under the `paths` section (rather than the *total* number of keys, which would be 12).  At the end of the answer, I show how to instead count the number of `tags` entries.

Using `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/:

```bsh
yq '.paths|length' file.yml
```

The output will be `3` for your example document.

The expression `.paths|length` passes the `paths` array to the `length` function. The function returns the length of the array.

To get this number in a shell variable, use a simple command substitution:

```bsh
number_of_paths=$( yq '.paths|length' file.yml )
```

If you instead want the sum of the number of `tags` entries (which may be much more than the entries in the top-level `paths` array):

```bsh
yq '[ .paths[].post.tags | length ] | add' file.yml
```

---

In a similar manner, using `yq` from https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/:

```bsh
yq eval '.paths|length' file.yml
```

or, for storing in a variable,

```bsh
number_of_paths=$( yq eval '.paths|length' file.yml )
```

Or, if it's the sum of the lengths of the `tags` arrays that you want:

```bsh
yq eval '[ .paths[].post.tags | length ] | .[] as $item ireduce(0; . + $item)' file.yml
```

Comment: Is there any other approach apart from yq?

Comment: @PrashanthSams Sure, using another `yq` parser. see updated answer.

Comment: Thank you; still is it possible to get the counts in native way without installing yq or external libs?

Comment: @PrashanthSams Like with `awk`, which is also an external tool?

Comment: but that comes by default and we dont need any special installations in it

Comment: is it possible to get the solution without yq?

Comment: @PrashanthSams Wait a bit and someone will give you both a `sed` and `awk` solution. I'm not going to be the one handing you fragile YAML parsing answers though.

Comment: it's okay - still I appreciate taking your time helping me :) - I did upvote as well

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use either of the `yq` parsers, perhaps you can use perl's [YAML::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/YAML::Tiny) module?

```
$ perl -MYAML::Tiny -E '
    my $yaml = YAML::Tiny->read("file.yaml"); say scalar keys %{ $yaml->[0]->{"paths"} }
'
3
```